# Angular firebase 5 get data value

Tags: angular, firebase

I'm new to angularJS and firebase. Recently I am working on a project, I try to after user login, users can pick up a username for themselves.
The problem is the tutorial I read is based on firebase 4. With the firebase 5 something changed.
The function not working is checkUsername
In ***AuthService.ts*** it looks like:

```
checkUsername(username: string){
    username = username.toLowerCase()
    return this.db.object(`usernames/${username}`)
}
```

Based on Firebase4 in the component.ts looks like

```
checkUsername(){

  this.authService.checkUsername(this.usernameText).subscribe(username =>{
  this.usernameAvaliable = !username.$value
})}
```

However, the .*subscribe* is no longer exist in firebase 5. I looked up some solution such as add valueChanged before subscribe. But it still not working properly.

The main function gets the username data value from firebase and checks if there any same username.

Is there anyone know what kind change I should do?

Answer (score 0):

I **can't comment** yet so get my answer as a comment, please.

Can you please create a Plunker and link it in order to give me some more code to see?

Anyway, this is the official guide to **[upgrade from AngularFire 4 to AngularFire 5](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md)**, if your problem was on one of those things, you can solve it just by **following their instructions**. If is not, the problem is **probably somewhere else**.